# inserting array values to mysql throws error

Tags: python, mysql

I am inserting array values to mysql but it throws some error.

Could not find where does the error occured and where is the error.

Error:

```
TypeError: 'Connection' object does not support indexing
```

Where is the error and what is the fix?

Comment: What is this `db1[9][0]` ?

Comment: Can you include more of your code? Like where you define both `db1` and `db`? Because you are indexing both of those

Comment: The first query you are showing has 10 values. The query in the error only has six values, yet you are formatting on eleven values...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `db` variable contains a `Connection` object instance. This `Connection` objects are not indexable, so `db[0]....db[n]` will not provide any values to be inserted in the SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant this

```
db1[1],db1[2]
```

Instead of this

```
db[1],db[2]
```

Comment: Really? Without seeing your code, I bet `db` is a Connection object as your error states